# Analog PWM generator from 0%

Tags: analog, pwm, 555

I have to prepare easy analog PWM regulator which can operate from 0% (0V). I know that one 555 can't do that...
Do you know any circuit that can handle that?

Answer (score 1):

Try the LTC6992 from Linear Technology for size: -

[image]